# Checkbox control in TFS witcommand

Tags: tfs

I have a custom TFS form. In this form i need to add a check box as

Select test:

Test1

Test2

Test3

Test1, Test2 and Test3 should be check box controls and the user can select any number of check boxes. How can I achieve this in TFS? I installed a code plex project http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/

But there is no documentation on how I can use the controls or samples.

Comment: Is your custom work item control a windows control (on VS) or a web control (on Web Access)?

Answer (score 0):

The download file from http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/ contains an installer for the Windows controls and a .zip file for the Web Access controls.

**To install windows control:**

Simply run the msi setup and restart Visual Studio.

Fields associated with multivalue control should have list of suggested values and each value enclosed in square brackets. For example:

```
<FIELD name="Triage" refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage" type="String" reportable="dimension">
<HELPTEXT>Status of triaging the bug</HELPTEXT>
<SUGGESTEDVALUES expanditems="false">
<LISTITEM value="[Approved]" />
<LISTITEM value="[Investigate]" />
<LISTITEM value="[Rejected]" />
<LISTITEM value="[Submit]" />
</SUGGESTEDVALUES>
</FIELD>
```

Then use MultiValueControl as controltype for that field in Form section, for example:

```
<Control Type="MultiValueControl" FieldName="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Triage" Label="Triag&amp;e:" LabelPosition="Left" />
```

Check: http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiValue%20Control

**To install web control:**

- Navigate in your browser to the configuration panel for the web
  extension of TFS: `http://servername:8080/tfs/_admin/_extensions`
- Click on the Install and upload the CodePlex.WitCustomControls.MultiValueControl.zip-file, make
  sure to use the .zip file matching you TFS server version.
- Enable the extension.

Check: http://witcustomcontrols.codeplex.com/releases/view/616048

Answer (score 0):

As of the recent release of TFS 2015 Update 2, this can be done with the witd in on-prem TFS like this (example is from a Bug).

Definition:

```
<FIELD name="CustomerReported" refname="X.X.CustomerReported" type="Boolean" reportable="dimension">
        <DEFAULT from="value" value="True" />
      </FIELD>
```

Layout:

```
<Control FieldName="X.X.CustomerReported" Type="FieldControl" Label="Customer Reported" LabelPosition="Left" />
```